# Dashed Object attached to primary object

Tags: objects

I hit some keys on accident and then noticed that there was a dashed box that is somehow attached to the object.  It is visible in object and edit mode but I cannot select it.
I thought it was a parenting issue, but I cannot find anything it is attached to and it is not a bounding box.  (It is a child of an empty).

See attached image.  Orange arrow pointing at mystery object.

Here is my Question:
What is it?
What does it do?
Do I need to get rid of it?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a texture space coordinates, that can be  enabled accidentally by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

You can disable it from display in Object properties on display panel:

[image]

Comment: Great & thank you!  I will read more into what exactly Texture Space coordinates are for sure!